# Trying to understand Phonegap and hybrid-app development

Tags: android, html, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am gearing up to create my first app using HTML5/CSS/Javascript. It will be a version of a web-app I am building on a page of my website, which allows the user to create customisable video sequences.

I am looking at the best way to also release this as a mobile app, and have been reading about Phonegap (though by all means suggest a better platform?). I'm just trying to understand what the "compiling" process actually does to the code. And when a "hybrid" app runs on a phone, what type of "browser" does it use?

For example, my app will make use of the HTML5 `<video>` element. Now, looking at [this reference guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) we can see that certain video formats aren't going to play on certain mobile browsers. So, how can I know if they are going to work on my Phonegap-complied hybrid app?